# How to check programmatically if "use wireless networks" is enabled on Android?

Tags: java, android, connection, wifi

I don't want to check if there is any connectivity over WIFI or 3G!
I just want to verify (and not change!) if the "Use wireless networks"-CheckBox is enabled (the one you can set in Settings > Location and security > My location > HERE)
Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code from RajaReddy will check if Wifi is enabled for network. If you want to know if Wifi is enabled for positioning then this should do (replace "context" with something useful)

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
boolean wifiEnabled = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(cr, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

example code for API Level < 8

```
private static boolean isWifiLocationEnabled (Context context) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String enabledProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(enabledProviders)) {
        // not the fastest way to do that :)
        String[] providersList = TextUtils.split(enabledProviders, ",");
        for (String provider : providersList) {
            if (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.equals(provider)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't have the method isLocationProviderEnabled in Settings.Secure. Can I access it somehow?

Comment: Ok that method is API Level 8 and above. `String allowedProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);` should get you a comma delimited list of enabled providers in which you can look for LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: That's it! The list contains "network,gps" when both options: "Use GPS satellites" and "Use wireless networks" are enabled. You made my day!

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
public Boolean isNetAvailable(Context con) {

   try {
      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

      if(wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
         return true;
      }
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return false;
}
```

and following permissions are required for this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: This works fine, but I still can't find out this way if the user has checked "use wireless networks" in his android-settings. The code above just checks if there is WIFI/Network connectivity...which is not what i ment.   sdf